# How to adjust java stack size when starting a java executable?

Tags: command-line, java

I'm setting up an OpenMQ environment, which is a java-based messaging middleware.

I run the command imqbrokerd, which is a java executable, to start a broker, but keep getting the following:

The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

To check the default setting, I used the command "java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version" and found the following entries related to stack size:

```
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize    = 0                                   
 intx ThreadStackSize            = 1024                                
 intx VMThreadStackSize          = 1024                                
 java version "1.8.0_201"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Is the '1024' above in byte or KB?

I know one can set the stack size with an -Xss512K option: java -Xss512K -j myjar.jar

But how do I do the same for starting a Java executable like imqbrokerd?

Thanks much for sharing your insight!

Comment: The manual https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/821-0027/aeokn/index.html says `/etc/opt/sun/mq/imqbrokerd.conf`

Comment: thanks much for pointing that out. I did as described in the document, but still get the same. Do I need to restart something for the change to take effect? I also did that with command line options -vmargs. same result:     /opt/Oracle/MessageQueue/mq/bin$ ./imqbrokerd -vmargs "-Xms384m -Xmx1024m" The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rinzwind! Following your hint, I found out, instead of as the document stated, I need to adjust the stack size with the `-Xss` instead of `-Xms` and `Xmx` flag. Then it started successfully:

```
/opt/Oracle/MessageQueue/mq/bin$ ./imqbrokerd -vmargs "-Xss384k"  

[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] 
================================================================================
Open Message Queue 4.5.2
Oracle
Version:  4.5.2  (Build 2-d)
Compile:  Thu Dec  8 17:30:48 PST 2011

Copyright (c) 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
================================================================================
Java Runtime: 1.8.0_201 Oracle Corporation /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT]    IMQ_HOME=/opt/Oracle/MessageQueue/mq
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] IMQ_VARHOME=/opt/Oracle/MessageQueue/var/mq
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] Linux 4.4.0-177-generic amd64 erdbeer (4 cpu) bfzhou
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] Java Heap Size: max=188416k, current=188416k
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] Arguments: 
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] [B1060]: Loading persistent data...
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] Using built-in file-based persistent store: /opt/Oracle/MessageQueue/var/mq/instances/imqbroker/
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:14 EDT] [B1270]: Processing messages from transaction log file...
[18/Jun/2020:16:15:15 EDT] [B1039]: Broker "imqbroker@erdbeer:7676" ready.
```